# Get time only of datetime

Tags: linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I have datetime variable `officeStartTime` which hold datetime value as

`officeStartTime = {9/24/2013 10:00:00 AM}`

and I have module `CHECKINOUT` which contain `userid`, `checktime` and other properties.

Now what I want is to get list of `CHECKINOUT` entries whose time part of checktime is greater than time part of `officeStartTime`.

I try:

`var checklist= con.CHECKINOUTs.Where(x => x.CHECKTIME.TimeOfDay > officeStartTime.TimeOfDay);`

`checklist` contains the following error is shown:

`{"The specified type member 'TimeOfDay' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported."}` .

It says `TimeOfDay` is not supported in LINQ to Entities, if so how can I check for time part of datetime in LINQ. Is there any other way to do this? Please suggest me what to do.

Thank you.

Comment: if the answer was helpful for you - upvote it please. If it was the solution - upvote and update

Comment: I posted this comment - cause as for today - you have 8 answer and 0 of them accepted, but almost all have responses.

Comment: @MikroDel I am trying according to your answer, and I will upvote for your response.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use

```
CreateTime(hour, minute, second)
```

from [Date and Time Canonical Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738563%28VS.100%29.aspx)

Comment: ok why not ..... And also it would be pleasure if you help me out to get some more reputation .......

Answer (score 9):

Use [EntityFunctions.CreateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.entityfunctions.createtime.aspx) method:

```
var checklist= from c in con.CHECKINOUTs
               let time = EntityFunctions.CreateTime(c.CHECKTIME.Hour,
                                                     c.CHECKTIME.Minute,
                                                     c.CHECKTIME.Second)
               where time > officeStartTime.TimeOfDay
               select c;
```

Fluent syntax:

```
con.CHECKINOUTs.Where(c => EntityFunctions.CreateTime(c.CHECKTIME.Hour, c.CHECKTIME.Minute, c.CHECKTIME.Second) > officeStartTime.TimeOfDay)
```

Comment: Note that for Entity Framework 6, this has changed to `DbFunctions.CreateTime`

Answer (score 5):

Just as a heads up, if you are using Entity Framework Version 6.0.0.0, `EntityFunctions` is **OUTDATED**.

The same functionality can be found under `DbFunctions`.

So for your answer, using EF6, it would look like this:

```
con.CHECKINOUTs.Where(c => DbFunctions.CreateTime(c.CHECKTIME.Hour, c.CHECKTIME.Minute, c.CHECKTIME.Second) > officeStartTime.TimeOfDay)
```

Hope this helps!